# unexplained syntax error defining threadpool inside class definition

Tags: c++, class, syntax

I have the following class definition and for some reason I cannot define the threadpool inside the class definition itself.  It says: syntax error: identifier 'numberofpoolthreads'  I tried directly defining it in the class, but it gives me same syntax error, does anyone know why this is?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/threadpool.hpp>
#include <boost/threadpool/pool.hpp>
#include <boost/threadpool/detail/pool_core.hpp>

typedef boost::threadpool::fifo_pool resolverpool;

class ResolverThreadPoolManager
{
public:
    ResolverThreadPoolManager::ResolverThreadPoolManager(int numberofpoolthreads);
    ResolverThreadPoolManager::~ResolverThreadPoolManager();

    resolverpool p(numberofpoolthreads);

private:
    int numberofpoolthreads;    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line: `resolverpool p(numberofpoolthreads);` isn't valid in a class definition.  You need a member variable, which you then initialise in the constructor.  e.g.:

```
class ResolverThreadPoolManager
{
public:
    explicit ResolverThreadPoolManager(int numberofpoolthreads);
    ...

private:
    const resolverpool p;
};

ResolverThreadPoolManager::ResolverThreadPoolManager(int numberofpoolthreads)
    : p(numberofpoolthreads)
    {}
```

Comment: normally you initialize the threadpool like this: boost::threadpool:fifo_pool pool(5), where 5 is the number of threadpool threads.  I want this number to be held in a variable, so how would I do this then?

Answer (score 0):

In your line
    resolverpool p(numberofpoolthreads);
the argument "numberofpoolthreads" is not a type, so this is a malformed declaration.  Perhaps
    resolverpool p(int numberofpoolthreads);
?  I imagine, perhaps incorrectly, that your error message also hints on which line the error occurred, which can help narrow down where in a file an error lies.  (Although, typically only indicating "error is on this or some previous line.")